# add class to element which grandgrandparent has no "display:none" style

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass

using `jQuery` I want to add `class` to `select` element if his grandgrandparent hasn't `style="display:none"` atribute

html is like this( here I **don't want** to add `class`):

```
<div style"display:none">
  <div>
    <div>
      <select></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here I **want** to add `class` to `select` element:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <select></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the missing equal sign :

```
style="display:none"
```

then you can just do :

```
$('select').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).parents().eq(2).is(':visible') ? 'myClass' : '';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XDdB/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this out (for grandparent):

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var grandparent = $(this).parent().parent();
    if(grandparent.is(':visible')) { //grandparent is not hidden
       // do something
    }
    else {
       // do something else
    }
});
```

Try this (for great-grandparent):

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var g_grandparent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    if(g_grandparent.is(':visible')) { //great-grandparent is not hidden
       // do something
    }
    else {
       // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't there be one more parent()?

Comment: @Learner No, your parent's parents' parent is your **great** grandparent. The post asked about "grand"parent... Hmmm but the code shows great grandparent. I _edited_ to add a "great"grandparent option.

Comment: Yes, he asked for grandparent but I guess his goal is to get great grand parent value as <div style"display:none"> is set for great grand parent.

Comment: @Learner as you can see, I (ninja) updated my answer to show an option for great grandparent as well.

Comment: Yes sir, I saw that and that's why you have 1 up-vote from me ;)

Comment: guys, I asked for GrandGrandparent, which in correct mean great grandparent. sorry for this confusion. firstly I think about how to do that only by selector, but guess it's impossible. this code is nice. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or this

```
$("select").filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().parent().parent().is(":visible");
}).addClass("visible");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qu7r/

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This finds the great grandparent of the select, checks for visibility and then adds the new class to the select for you:

```
var element = $("select").parent().parent().parent();
if(element.is(":visible")) {
    element.find("select").addClass("new-added-class");
}
```

Check it out on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MyzmB/)

Comment: this will not work. I think because you work with all selects together. just check  http://jsfiddle.net/MyzmB/